# Variable unexpectedly changed to 0 after cin to different variable

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my program in c++: this program unexpectedly sets my variable `n_alunni` to `0` when I `cin >> verify;` even though I haven't written anything else to `n_alunni`.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n_alunni=1;
    char verify[1];

    cout<<"Inserisci il numero di alunni: ";
    cin>>n_alunni; // I set it to something > 0

    cout<<n_alunni; // n_alunni > 0
    cout<<"Sicuro di voler inserire "<<n_alunni<<" alunni (y,n)?   ";
    cin>>verify;      // <-- After I insert into verify, n_alunni suddenly equals 0
    cout<<n_alunni; // n_alunni == 0
}
```

Can anyone help me please, thanks everyone in advance

Comment: Why is `verify` an array consisting of a single `char` and not just a `char` itself? I don't know how `std::istream::operator>>` handles `char[]` and wouldn't be surprised if it's causing undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: Supposedly since C++ 11, if  'cin' fails, it will write a 0 and set the 'failbit' which you can check by looking at the return value of cin.fail(). It doesn't make much sense to me that it would be overwriting `n_alunni` when assigning to `verify` but I'd see what you get when you `cout << cin.fail();`  after the cin>>verify line. As Nathan points out it may be behaving strangely to try to cin to the char[]

Comment: "_after i insert the `y` the value of n_alunni go to `0`_" - You also insert a null terminator (`\0`) in your array that has place for 1 char. So, you write 2 `char`s,  `y` and `\0`. This causes _undefined behavior_  and the behavior was probably to overwrite a part of the memory where your `n_alunni` variable is stored.

Comment: @TedLyngmo could you rewrite your comment as an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @RobG I had dinner, but I'll upvote both your answers instead :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter said in his answer, and TomLyngmo in his comment, trying to `cin` to a `char[]` (`verify`) makes C++ think you want to write a C-string, which always has a 'null terminator' to indicate the end of the string. However, your `char[]` is only length 1, so unless you don't insert anything into it, it will try to write beyond the end of the array, causing this undefined behavior (changing other variables randomly).

Since your `verify` doesn't need to be a C-string, you could change it to just `char verify` and remove any of the array-access business from it. `cin`  should then see it as a proper char and not try to write any null terminator after it, avoiding the memory overwrite you're seeing that results in unexpectedly changing the value of the other variable to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The input into `verify` is writing beyond the array bounds, overwriting other memory, among it your variable. Use `std::string instead` or at least increase the array size beyond the expected input length (and, for a safe program, protect against boundary violations!).

In more detail, the array argument is, as is the case in many contexts, "adjusted" to a pointer to char; this matches the `istream& operator>> (istream& is, char* s)`. This operator copies a "word" from the standard input into the memory pointed to. It skips any whitespace (for example, the newline left behind from when you last hit the enter key) and then copies characters from stdin to the indicated memory location; it stops before the next whitespace in the input (for example, the newline produced when you hit the enter key to "finish your input"). After the input characters are written the routine terminates the entered 1-character "word" with a null character so that it is a proper "C string" after the crude fashion that was modern in 1978.

If you entered a one-character word, that null character gets written to memory adjacent to your 1-char array, in this case `n_alunni`. (You can verify that hypothesis by entering a number into `n_alunni` that is larger than 255, thus altering more bytes which will not be affected by the zero byte. On an intel architecture the new value of `n_alunni` after a one-character input should then be `n_alunni & ~0xff`; that is, the same as after the input with the lowest byte zeroed out).

As is often the case, using `std::string` for text is a safer way to handle unknown text. There is an [`istream& operator>> (istream& is, string& str)`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/) that works just like the `char *` overload, only safer.